# How to join filtered results to get this?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, textjoin

I'm using this filter functions through out a column:

```
=FILTER({$A$3:$A, $L$3:$L}, $E$3:$E =F4)
```

The output is obviously 2 columns and could be 2-4 number of rows:
[image: output]
I want the output data in a single cell like this: **1(24,655)+2(10,000)**
If that is impossible than at least this: 1-24,655 / 2-10,000

The closest I managed is just to put the data in single cell by using textjoin: `=textjoin("-",1,FILTER(..))`
which resulted in: 1-24,655-2-10,000 (I have no clue what further can I do)
Please Help!

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=JOIN("+", FILTER({A3:A&"("&L3:L&")"}, E3:E=F4))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, Can you please tell me how can convert it to Arrayformula? I tried this: =ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("+", FILTER({A3:A&"("&L3:L&")"}, E3:E=F3:F))) But this just gives 1 output i.e. ()+()+()+()+....(Those are empty brackets) Please Help!

Comment: @AashitGarodia JOIN is not supported by ArrayFormula. can you share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result?

Comment: Damn  I'm trying it down since hours now :(, I'm creating a new file to share it with you! Also How do you decide what works in Arrayformula and what not, I realized even functions like OR doesn't work in ArrayFormula. Is there any good material I can read upon? Please put some light on it

Comment: @AashitGarodia yes, OR, AND, JOIN, SUM and few more are not supported under AF tho there is always some workaround how to make it work. sadly there is no official guide which functions do not work under arrayformula.

Comment: That is really unexpected. Here is the link for for my new question to convert the Formula to ArrayFormula. I request you to answer this! https://support.google.com/docs/thread/111783407/how-to-decide-which-formulas-work-in-arrayformula-which-doesn-t-also-convert-these-formulas-to-af?hl=en&msgid=111783407

Comment: @AashitGarodia D3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gio9a.png

Comment: @AashitGarodia H3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqTlr.png

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, You literally solved it in 10 min that's very genius. How are you so comfortable with this AF? I think I'm going to take hours understanding the solution & still won't get it all.

Comment: Is your username 0 0 2846 in google community? It commented the your answer itself. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/111783407/how-to-decide-which-formulas-work-in-arrayformula-which-doesn-t-also-convert-these-formulas-to-af?hl=en&msgid=111787096

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67781404/please-help-me-with-the-formula-arrayformula I got a new question, please help!