# Please help me with the Formula & ArrayFormula:

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

**I want to return TRUE for blank cells until last value** (check out the Required column)

[image]

I tried this formula: `=AND($A2="" ,$A3:$A <> "")` but it didn't work.
**Question 1**: How can I make 2nd argument i.e. `$A3:$A <> ""` return **true** **if any one cell in the range** $A3:$A is **Not Null**? Final Formula?
(I know my formula is wrong because it doesn't check every cell in the range mentioned if it is NULL or not, how can I make it check every cell?)

**Question 2**: ArrayFormula for the corresponding Formula.

(Please suggest if there's any better way to get the Formula & ArrayFromula along with the solution of the method I tried)
Here is the sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VF38MNcP1e4ieZY47QQq1zOwGYWAmuJ2k9A0WkGYeX0/edit?usp=sharing

**EDIT:**

**I got the Formula:** `=IFNA(MATCH(FALSE,ArrayFormula(isblank(A2:A)),0),0)>1`
For ArrayFormula I just tried wrapping it around but it didn't work: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(MATCH(FALSE,ArrayFormula(isblank(A2:A)),0),0)>1)`

**I just need the ArrayFormula of this Formula & please tell me what's wrong in my ArrayFormula?**
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(IF(A2:A="",,ROW(A2:A))))="")
```

or:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX((A2:A<>"")*ROW(A2:A)))="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please help me with another question? I literally learned from you and tried to apply the same but it didn't work: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/112748721/please-help-me-with-a-arrayformula-for-this-requirement-results?hl=en&msgid=113121605

Comment: I really can't thank you enough! I'm sorry to bother you so much, if possible can you please tell me what's wrong in my Rank Arrayformula: https://rb.gy/fuhsks (I used this answer of yours as reference : https://rb.gy/g1lwk0)

Comment: @AashitGarodia not rly sure whats your question but see if this helps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO6FU.png

Comment: Thank you, I actually created a question to be more clear, Hope I'm clear enough this time! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67975406/please-help-me-correcting-my-arrayformula-for-this-required-result

Answer (score 2):

Try below formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(A2:A10="")
```

For full column

```
=ArrayFormula(A2:A="")
```

[image]

> ***Edit:*** Then use below formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,2):INDEX(A:A,MAX(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A),0)))="")
```

Comment: Thank you but that does not give the required column, It would give TRUE for rows 26,27,28 which are supposed to be FALSE because Last Value is in row 25. Please check the EDIT of my question.

Comment: @AashitGarodia Please see my edited formula. Also see your sheet.

Comment: Thank You so much! can you please tell me what was wrong in my ArrayFormula & also can you please explain the formula you gave? So I tried understanding, the only thing I understood is MAX(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A),0)) will give the last row with value i.e 25 in our case so the it becomes =ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,2):INDEX(A:A,25)=""). I understand INDEX(A:A,2) will return 2 & INDEX(A:A,25) will return 7 in my case BUT WHAT I DON'T UNDERSTAND IS HOW =INDEX(A:A,2):INDEX(A:A,25) GIVES AN ARRAY OF VALUES OF RANGE A2:A25, isn't it actually equal to writing =2:25 which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AashitGarodia Ha ha ha. Little bit tricky. It works like `INDIRECT()` or `OFFSET()` formula but those are volatile but `INDEX()` not volatile. So, when you are using `=Index(arr,x):Index(arr,y)` then it will return full range between `x & y` row. It is not documented but excel works in this way.

Comment: Damn that was really tricky but a very useful one, I just got one simple question: Your Formula `=INDEX(A:A,2):INDEX(A:A,25)=""` when wrapped around ArrayFormula: `=ArrayFormula(INDEX(A:A,2):INDEX(A:A,25)="")` worked, similarly my Formula `=IFNA(MATCH(FALSE,ArrayFormula(isblank(A2:A)),0),0)>1` when wrapped around ArrayFormula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(MATCH(FALSE,ArrayFormula(isblank(A2:A)),0),0)>1)` doesn't work, **Why? & How could I get ArrayFormula of my Formula?**

Comment: Please let me know if we can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this simple formula:

`=ArrayFormula(NOT(A2:A))`

Since any value equates to TRUE and null equates to FALSE, wrapping the range in `NOT` will return the opposite.

**ADDENDUM:**

Given additional information from poster:

`=ArrayFormula(IF((A2:A="")*(ROW(A2:A)<VLOOKUP(TRUE,SORT({A2:A<>"",ROW(A2:A)},2,0),2,FALSE)),TRUE,FALSE))`

Comment: Thank you but that does not give the required column, It would give TRUE for rows 26,27,28 which are supposed to be FALSE because Last Value is in row 25. Please check the EDIT of my question.

Comment: See the additional formula in my post.